# Javascript function - style change not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a 2 simple functions but function 2 doesn't work, I tried to change it to `style.font-weight = "bold";` but then all crashes, what to do?

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "hello world!";
  }
}

function validate2() {
  if (document.getElementById('remember2').checked) {
    document.getElementById("text").style = "bold";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").style = "normal";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text" style="font-weight: normal">hello world!</div>
<input id="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()">Caps</input>
<br>
<input id="remember2" type="checkbox" onclick="validate2()">Bold</input>
```

Is that a chrome problem or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't specifying the css property to be changed:

```
document.getElementById("text").style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

Javascript uses `camelCase` instead of a dash(`camel-case`), as CSS does, so `style.font-weight` is invalid.

```js
var textEl = document.getElementById("text");

function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
    textEl.innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD!";
  } else {
    textEl.innerHTML = "hello world!";
  }
}

function validate2() {
  if (document.getElementById('remember2').checked) {
    textEl.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  } else {
    textEl.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text">hello world!</div>
<input id="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" /> Caps
<br/>
<input id="remember2" type="checkbox" onclick="validate2()" /> Bold
```

Also note that your `<input>` syntax is incorrect, inputs are self-closing tags and their text is set with the `value` attribute(in this case the input is a checkbox, and can't have a value):

```
<input id="remember2" type="checkbox" onclick="validate2()" />Bold
```

Comment: The only thing I would change is the upper case bit to document.getElementById("text").style.textTransform = "uppercase"; just so it'll work even with different text.

Comment: @AndrewBone I think the better option would be to use `toUpperCase();` instead, `text-transform` only changes how the text is rendered, if you copy and past the text, it shows up in lowercase. It is a really minor problem though :)

Comment: @JacobGray Actually, closing an input tag is better than not closing it. If you would run it through a strict HTML validator, not closing an input would fail. But yes text between the input tags is not valid.

Comment: @Mikey didn't know that. What about using the `<input />` syntax?

Comment: @JacobGray That is valid HTML, `<input></input>` is valid XHTML, but allmost all valid XHTML is valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

use this may help you

```
function validate2() {
    if (document.getElementById('remember2').checked) {
        document.getElementById("text").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("text").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have also fixed the .style = "normal" part maybe

Answer (score 2):

```
function validate2() {
    if (document.getElementById('remember2').checked) {
        document.getElementById("text").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("text").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were not setting the correct style property.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");

function validate(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.toLowerCase()
  }
}

function validate2(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    text.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  } else {
    text.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="text" style="font-weight: normal">hello world!</div>
  <input id="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate(this)">Caps</input>
  <br>
  <input id="remember2" type="checkbox" onclick="validate2(this)">Bold</input>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```